# can you manualy make standalone python executeable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, executable

the question '''Process to convert simple Python script into Windows executable''' does not answer mine. I have tried many programs to make an executable, but either they dont have any simple tutorial or documentation, or they just dont work.

I want to know if it is not too complex to manualy turn a python script into a standalone version. The programs I have tried to do this automaticly with have either been to complex, not compatible with my version of python, or just make extremly large files.

If it is way to complicated to do, I wont bother. also if anyone knows of a SIMPLE program to do this with that dosnt make large files and works with python 2.7, windows vista 32 bit, I would prefer that than to manualy do it all the time.

Py2.exe does not work with python 2.7 for some reason. I get an error while installing it.

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: Already tried that. dosnt work with python 2.7

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52

I've used it in the past. It's a little difficult, but once you get the tutorial running, hacking it up to your project is straightforward.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate. the question 'Process to convert simple Python script into Windows executable' does not answer mine. I have tried many programs to make an executable, but either they dont have any simple tutorial or documentation, or they just dont work.